# OpenGL Large Textures

Tags: opengl, gpu, textures

I know there are questions like this one out there, but I think this is seperate.  For a Minecraft-like world, I have a texture atlas.  Will there be a performance difference between a 1024x1024 atlas (mostly empty space) and a 100x100 atlas?  Does it re-upload the data to the GPU every frame, or does it only upload it once?  Because I would like to have a big atlas so I don't have to resize it for new blocks and textures, but will the empty space just bog down the application on lower-end computers?

I don't think so, because the data is stored on the GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will there be a performance difference between a 1024x1024 atlas (mostly empty space) and a 100x100 atlas

In theory yes, but 1024x1024 isn't exactly a large texture by ... the standards of this decade(including iGPUs).

> Does it re-upload the data to the GPU every frame

OpenGL does nothing you don't ask it for.*

Comment: The statement "OpenGL does nothing you don't ask for" isn't true. As a matter of fact, all widespread OpenGL implementations have their very own ideas of when which operations to perform. And due to the memory model of OpenGL (or rather the lack of such) it's undetermined, when exactly what transfer might happen. So the worries of OP are not unfounded.

Comment: @datenwolf I was considering adding a disclaimer here but in this context I deemed it to be true as the OP is not asking about repeatedly calling `glTexSubImage2D` or the likes but just in general "is opengl uploading texture data every frame" as if opengl would setup all its memory from scratch every frame which I find highly unlikely no matter how arcane the driver.

Comment: It actually depends on the texture. Given a texture large enough, it can and will happen. But we're talking textures that are a significant fraction of GPU memory in size.